# Free software for viewing blurays

Tags: windows, blu-ray

When viewing movies on my PC, VLC is my software of choice. Unfortunately, it does not read blurays. I know the two big names are WinDVd and PowerDVD, but is there a free alternative for viewing blurays on my PC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).  It has everything you need including MPC (Media Player Classic).